# Intersection points of a function and its inverse.

Tags: functions

Why is it that when $f$ is an increasing function then the points of intersection of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ lie on the line $y=x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y)$ is an intersection point of $f$ and $f^{-1}$. Then $f(x)=y$ and $f^{-1}(x)=y$, thus $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$. If $x < y$ this would mean that $f$ is not increasing on $[x,y]$, whereas $x>y$ would mean that $f$ is not increasing on $[y,x]$. Hence $x=y$, implying that $(x,y)$ lies on the line $y=x$.

Comment: How exactly does $x<y \implies f \text{ is decreasing on }[x,y]$? All I see is that $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x<y$.

Comment: It means that the function cannot be increasing on $[x,y]$, since in that case we would have $f(y) \geq f(x)$.

Comment: Functions can be both non increasing and non decreasing.

Comment: You're absolutely right, which is why I edited my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I missed that the question says that $f$ is increasing